# New Umbraco 7 - no admin links in settings panel

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I've installed Umbraco 7.18 via Microsoft Web Platform installer..
It downloaded, installed, and setup correctly from what I can see.

However, I've logged onto the CMS, and don't have any CMS admin options in the left hand settings panel, nor can I see how I can edit any pages..
I am sure I am missing something quite obvious, but hopefully someone can help me here.

I've checked my username properties (seems to be the only admin feature I can open), and I am set as an administrator..

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To help others who this may happen too, the solution is to simply clear all your cookies, and restart the browser.

Strange that you have to do this on a newly installed solution, but there you go!